# Not able to use px.timeline in streamlit - working in google collab

Tags: python, plotly, streamlit

I used to have a successfully deployed app using the plotly timeline graph but since a few months I always have the error

> TypeError: Object of type timedelta is not JSON serializable

I used the same code below in my IDE and it works so I am a bit confused on the issue, I updated to streamlit-1.27.2 and the issue remains

```
import plotly.express as px
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([
    dict(Task="Job A", Start='2009-01-01', Finish='2009-02-28'),
    dict(Task="Job B", Start='2009-03-05', Finish='2009-04-15'),
    dict(Task="Job C", Start='2009-02-20', Finish='2009-05-30')
])

fig = px.timeline(df, x_start="Start", x_end="Finish", y="Task")
fig.update_yaxes(autorange="reversed") # otherwise tasks are listed from the bottom up
st.plotly_chart(fig)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can reproduce the `TypeError` with `plotly<=5.14.0` and `pandas>=2.0.0`.

It has nothing to do with `streamlit`. It was actually a [*bug*](https://github.com/plotly/plotly.py/issues/4145) in plotly and was fixed in [`5.14.1`](https://github.com/plotly/plotly.py/releases/tag/v5.14.1).

As a solution, you can either downgrade `pandas` to `<2.0.0` or upgrade plotly to `>=5.14.1`.

```
#1st solution
pip install pandas==1.5.3

#2nd solution
pip install plotly==5.14.1 # or pip install -U plotly
```

Output (`streamlit run app.py`):

[image]

Comment: wow thank you!! I could not find it online